# After taking max agg on dataframe I am unable to use it to load into pandas sql insert

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pyodbc

I have used the following code snippet to take out max per deviceid :

```
insert_df_todb = insert_df.groupby('DeviceId')['timestamp'].agg(['max']).reset_index()
```

Assume following is my data :

```
timestamp                   |   DeviceId
: -----------------------   |   : -----------------------
2020-11-30 10:00:00+00:00   |   T100022
2020-11-30 11:00:00+00:00   |   T100022
2020-11-30 12:00:00+00:00   |   T100022
2020-11-30 13:00:00+00:00   |   T100023
2020-11-30 14:00:00+00:00   |   T100023
2020-11-30 15:00:00+00:00   |   T100024
2020-11-30 16:00:00+00:00   |   T100025
2020-11-30 17:00:00+00:00   |   T100025
2020-11-30 18:00:00+00:00   |   T100022
2020-11-30 19:00:00+00:00   |   T100025
```

Now once I get the data into a dataframe I am trying to loop through it and insert a SQL table as follows :

```
for index,row in insert_df_todb.iterrows():
     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [inspection].[inspection_timestamp] ([timestamp],[device_id]) values(?,?)",row.max,row.DeviceId)
```

Here I am getting the following error :

```
ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=method', 'HY105')
```

I tried inserting the deviceid field alone, there is no problem it inserts. The error comes when its trying to insert the max timestamp column.

I checked the type of the columns and it says :

```
<bound method Series.max of DeviceId                     T045D735
max         2021-01-10 15:00:00+00:00
Name: 0, dtype: object>
```

Why cant life be made more simple and just make it a simple regular series ?

How do I convert this into a usable format for my scenario, I tried a couple of them to no avail.

Comment: convert the timestamp to string `insert_df_todb['timestamp'].astype(str).str[:19]`, and try again?

Comment: sorry for late reply, same issue persists.

Comment: I have changed the way I was aggregating and taking out the max and its working now :  ```insert_df_todb = insert_df.groupby(['DeviceId'])['timestamp'].max().reset_index() ```